# MATLAB ODBC SQL Server Driver SQL Server Invalid column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, matlab

I get the below error when i execute my query:

> Message: 'ODBC Driver Error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Invalid column name 'SSC%'.'

I wrote my query like this:

```
"query = 'select top 500 * from [dbo].[accu_HISTORY_CONFIG] WHERE Description LIKE "SSC%"';"
```

I am new to the MATLAB database explorer. Basically I was trying to find all the "Descriptions" that contains the first three letters "SSC." However, I keep getting this "invalid column name" error. I suspect that MATLAB treated my `"SSC%"` as a column name? How should I fix this? Any suggestion will be much appreciated!!

Teng

Comment: Use single quotes for string literals. (Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, e.g. column names.) `...WHERE Description LIKE 'SSC%'`.

Comment: @jarlh thanks for the advice. Yes I tried it. In fact, originally I was using such format. However, "%" is treated as comment in Matlab. If you just use single quotes, the last three symbols, 
 will turn green (as comments)

Comment: Perhaps your environment needs double single quotes? I.e. `...WHERE Description LIKE ''SSC%''';´

Answer (score 1):

' ends the string for matlab, but you want the ' inside your string. if you want to do that just use it twice:

```
query = 'select top 500 * from [dbo].[accu_HISTORY_CONFIG] WHERE Description LIKE ''SSC%'' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically your wildcard statement would be kept in single quotes.

So it would typically be

```
'select top 500 * from [dbo].[accu_HISTORY_CONFIG] WHERE Description LIKE 'SSC%''
```

If not, this help article should cover what you need.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/222664